# Python 3 builtins.NameError: global name --- is not defined -

Tags: python, python-3.x, nameerror

Need some guidance here please. This is probably a stupid mistake, but I'm getting the "builtins.NameError: global name -- is not defined" error and I'm not seeing why - I'm still learning the language :).

Here is my code:

```
def option(x):
    if x == "E":
        enter()
    elif x == "V":
        view()
    else:
        exit()

def enter():
    msg = input("Enter the message\n")
    main()

def view():
    ##if msg == 0:
    #print("no message yet")
    #main()
    #else:
    print("The message is:", msg )
    main()        

def exit():
    print("Goodbye!")


def main():
    print("Welcome to BBS")
    print("MENU")
    print("(E)nter a message")
    print("(V)iew message")
    print("e(X)it")
    print("Enter your selection:")
    choice = input()
    option(choice)
    #msg = 0

main()
```

My problem is that I'm getting this even though I'm choosing the "E" option first:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Wing IDE 101 5.0\src\debug\tserver\_sandbox.py", line 36, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Wing IDE 101 5.0\src\debug\tserver\_sandbox.py", line 33, in main
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Wing IDE 101 5.0\src\debug\tserver\_sandbox.py", line 3, in option
    pass
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Wing IDE 101 5.0\src\debug\tserver\_sandbox.py", line 11, in enter
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Wing IDE 101 5.0\src\debug\tserver\_sandbox.py", line 33, in main
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Wing IDE 101 5.0\src\debug\tserver\_sandbox.py", line 5, in option
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Wing IDE 101 5.0\src\debug\tserver\_sandbox.py", line 18, in view
builtins.NameError: global name 'msg' is not defined
```

Could I please be guided? I've been searching for info and haven't found anything, and my conclusion is that it is probably something really stupid and noobish.

Also, as you guys can see from what I've commented out, I've attempted to restrict "view" from giving an error by checking that msg != 0 -- I made msg = 0 in main() - this obviously doesn't work because after going through enter() it goes back to main() and makes msg == 0 again. Could you guys link me to a page/guide that will help me understand how to solve this? I don't want to be spoon fed that much..

Thanks,

Itachi

Comment: Take a look at this article about [scope](http://gettingstartedwithpython.blogspot.com/2012/05/variable-scope.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that `msg` inside `enter()` is a local variable: it's created when the `enter()` function runs, and it ceases to exist when `enter()` returns. Normally, whenever you set a variable inside a function, you're setting a local variable. If you want to set a *global* variable, which retains its value even after the function returns, use a `global` statement:

```
def enter():
    global msg
    msg = input("Enter the message\n")
    main()
```

That said, global variables are often not the best way to do things. It may be better to have the `enter()` function return the message instead of storing it in a variable.

Answer (score 0):

`msg` is a name that's not scoped to be used anywhere.  That's why you get the `NameError`.

Each one of the functions you've created should stand alone and have straightforward inputs and outputs.

`main` is your entry point and it should call other functions as appropriate.

Those functions will return to their caller when their execution is complete.  They can and in some cases should return some amount of data back to their caller.

For example, here's a subset of your problem showing how `main` invokes `view` and then returns:

```
def view(text):
    if not text:
        print("no message yet")
    else:
        print("The message is:", msg )

def main():
    print("Welcome to BBS")
    print("MENU")
    print("(E)nter a message")
    print("(V)iew message")
    print("e(X)it")
    print("Enter your selection:")
    while not exiting:
        choice = input()
        view(choice)
        exiting = True # TODO: set this based on the value in choice
```